# xml.value()in Xquery only returns 1 record

Tags: sql-server, xquery-sql

I have multiple "abc" nodes in xml file but it is returning the value for the first row as we have specified [1] , if I write [2] , it returns the second row.

I want to return all the values of "**Element**" in all "abc" loops.

Query Used:

```
Insert Into @temp(aa,bb)
SELECT 
y.b.value('(abc/Segment/Element)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') ,
y.b.value('(abc/Segment/Element)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') 
FROM @x.nodes('(a1/b1/c1)') AS y(b)
```

Below Query is giving the desired result but I can't use the query as I need to access other fields from location a1/b1/c1 in same query

```
Insert Into @temp(aa,bb)
SELECT 
y.b.value('(Segment/Element)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') ,
y.b.value('(Segment/Element)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') 
FROM @x.nodes('(a1/b1/c1/abc)') AS y(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `cross apply` on `y.b` to get the rows for `abc`.

```
select z.b.value('(Segment/Element)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') ,
       z.b.value('(Segment/Element)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') 
from @x.nodes('(a1/b1/c1)') as y(b)
  cross apply y.b.nodes('abc') as z(b);
```